# Actions on Google authentication is not returning tokens

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito, actions-on-google

I'm integrating my smarthome services on the Actions on Google platform and I have some problems during the authentication process.

I have an Amazon Cognito user pool configured that I'm using for authentication, and apparently works fine, but I never receive the token on any request sent from Google to my back-end services.

The official documentation says the following:
"When you have authenticated a user, the user's third-party OAuth 2 access token is sent in the Authorization header when smart home intents are sent to your fulfillment."
But in fact, I don't receive that token.

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "0": {
            "intent": "action.devices.SYNC"
        }
    },
    "requestId": "7597788060327530693"
}
```

My account linking configuration:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLaVN.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've posted is the request *body*. The *headers* should exist as a separate object in your request, which will be a key-value pair of metadata. One datum should be `Authorization`.

Comment: Thank you very much Nick. I wasn't parsing and using the _headers_  object. In fact, the problem was in my API Gateway (I'm using Lambda functions on AWS), that wasn't configured to send the _headers_  object to the Lambda, only the _body_ of a request. After I properly configured my API Gateway, then the Lambda function started to received the _headers_ as well, including the `Authorization` token that I needed.